# How to add Slate node in particular empty space without selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slate, slatejs

Assume I have to add some custom element to Slatejs document by clicking toolbar outside the editor. It triggers `Transform.insertNodes` but instead of add element in place of cursor (which disappeared on click on toolbar and lost selection) it puts my element at the end of the document. Using `Locations` like `Point` or `Range` will not help because I do not know current position of cursor and I do not see any helper which would follow the cursor position.

So, how to put my element on cursor's place?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an issue of `editor.selection` becoming null when focus is lost, which is a [known issue](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/3412).

There are a few work arounds. One is to keep track of the selection yourself:

```
<Slate
  ...
  onBlur={() => {
    editor.lastSelection = editor.selection;
  }}
/>
...
Transforms.select(editor, editor.lastSelection)
Transforms.insertNodes(...,) // this will no work
```

The other approach is to monkey patch [Transforms.deselect to disallow losing the selection.](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/3412#issuecomment-573352323)